# Coin weighing - heaviest or lightest

Tags: strategy, weighing

> I have 6 coins
> Each coin has different weight
> I can weigh as many coins at a time on a scale (for example I can weigh 3 vs 2)

I want to determine which coin is second heaviest *or* second lightest in least possible weighings. How do I do that?

Comment: Ask the other scale what this one would do if Monte asks it to switch curtains.

Comment: Are you just making these up without finding the solution yourself?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I'm not really sure how it goes here. Do I post a puzzle and then an answer in the comments straight away?

Comment: The thing is, most puzzlers in here will get tired if you post a puzzle that is very similar to a puzzle asked the previous day. Especially if you posted the previous puzzle.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oh okay, thank you for the clarification then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same program that answered [the previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118794/75318), and its proposition that only 1v1 weighings are reasonable since there is no information about the absolute weights, apply here as well.

> Seven weighings are required in the worst case. Weigh three pairs $A<B,C<D,E<F$. Then sort $A<C<E$ using 3 weighings. Then the second-lightest coin is the lighter of $B$ and $C$.